# Blender render looks different than Substance creation

Tags: shaders

I imported my blender mesh to substance, but when I imported the textures I created from substance back to blender, it seemed to have lost a lot of detail. What did I do wrong?

Image 1 is the nodes

[image: Nodes used for blender]

Image 2 is the substance painter image

[image: final product in blender]

Image 3 is the final product in blender

[image: Nodes used for blender]

Comment: Metals are entirely dependent on the background they are reflecting for their detail.

Comment: Got it. So what would you recommend me put as a background so that I can see it? Thank you for your response!

Comment: You set a [hdri](https://hdrihaven.com/) as an *environment texture* for your world background.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it! A side question, that is totally fine if you are not able to answer, I was trying to add an image of text onto the texture to create the ring of power from Lord of the Rings, but could not figure out how to do it in Substance or in Blender. Any ideas? Thank you!